# How can I change directories in a homebrew formula?

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I am trying to create my own homebrew formula using `brew create` and `brew edit` .

As part of the install for this project I need to change into a sub directory and build things there, for example

```
cd sub/dir/place
make -f makefile otherMakeTarget
```

I tried adding to my formula.rb

```
system "cd", "sub/dir/place/"
system "make", "etc"
```

But it doesn't seem to do the cd correctly.  The logfile 01.cd shows the cd and the argument on two separate lines, I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: Each `system` starts a new process, so your `make` doesn't run in the directory you changed to in the previous `system` process. I don't know the syntax in Ruby, but you probably need `system "cd","somewhere","&&","make"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `system` creates a subshell and any modifications to the working directory go away when that call completes.

You could try using [`chdir`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-chdir):

```
Dir.chdir('sub/dir/place')
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is to use a `chdir` block.

```rb
    chdir "vendor" do
      system "make", "install"
    end
```